# winforms tab page event not firing

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol, tabpage

I have a `TabControl` to which the user can add tab pages.

I am trying to attach some events to it such as: `MouseEnter`, `MouseLeave`, `MouseClick`, But it seems the these events are not firing at all, they only fire when I attach them to the `TabControl` itself, but this is not what I need.

What is the problem with attaching events to a tab control tab page ?

Here is my latest attempt to attach these event from my code:

```
private void customerTabCtrl_ControlAdded(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
{
   TCTabPage tctab = (TCTabPage)e.Control; // Option A
   TCTabPage tctab = (TCTabPage)customerTabCtrl.Controls[customerTabCtrl.Controls.Count - 1]; //Option B
   tctab.MouseEnter += new EventHandler(tctab_MouseEnter);
   tctab.MouseLeave += new EventHandler(tctab_MouseLeave);
}
```

Comment: "they only fire when I attach them to the tab control it self, but this is not what I need." - Where do you need to attach the events then?

Comment: How do you exactly attach events to *user added tab pages*?

Comment: show us the code where you attach the event.

Comment: Here is my latest attemp to attach it:
`private void customerTabCtrl_ControlAdded(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
        {
                TCTabPage tctab = (TCTabPage)e.Control; //option A
                TCTabPage tctab = (TCTabPage)customerTabCtrl.Controls[customerTabCtrl.Controls.Count - 1]; // Option B
                tctab.MouseEnter += new EventHandler(tctab_MouseEnter);
                tctab.MouseLeave += new EventHandler(tctab_MouseLeave);
        }`

Comment: your code looks fine, what is inside the added `tabpage`? Make sure your new `tabpage` not get covered by other controls.

Comment: I also thought about it, that maybe it is coverd, but how can I check it ? There where other people beofor me who worked on this code...

Comment: ...can't you just see it in the code/interface?

Comment: I can see the tab header, it's  a tab...

Comment: check `tctab.Controls.Count`?

Comment: The tab is not empty, It has a user control in it called "CustomerTabControl" which contains alot ot controls also...

Comment: So you need to identify the `control` in front that your MouseEnter/MouseLeave is really relevant to, and then handle its events.

Comment: I used this code: `int x = tabPage.Parent.Controls.GetChildIndex(tabPage);` and got that x = 0. Does it mean that it is not covered ?

Comment: no, your code returns the index of `tabPage` of its `Parent`, to get the amount of controls inside the `tabPage` use `tabPage.Controls.Count`

Comment: I used it. I told you above, it has only one user control in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need an event for this since by default, the end user cannot add TabPages to the TabControl without you providing the code for it.

So wherever you are adding the TabPage, that's when you should wiring up those events:

```
TCTabPage tctab = new TCTabPage();
tbtab.Text = "New Tab";
tctab.MouseEnter += tctab_MouseEnter;
tctab.MouseLeave += tctab_MouseLeave;
customerTabCtrl.TabPages.Add(tctab);
```

Comment: I tryied it, but still not working...
Here is what I did with your solution: 
`CustomerTabPage newCustomerTab = new CustomerTabPage(...);
                    newCustomerTab.MouseEnter += new EventHandler(tabPage_MouseEnter);
                    customerTabCtrl.Controls.Add(newCustomerTab);`

Answer (score 1):

I fill so silly...
I found out the "problem", I thought that the MouseEnter, MouseLeave, MouseClick events should fire even when the cursor is on the tab header, but it appears that these events fire only when the cursor is at the tab body...
Sory for the trouble, I am using winforms only 6 months now...