# How to check Mouse Out on a Tab area of TabPage in C# Winform?

Tags: c#, winforms, mouseevent, tabcontrol

I want to check Mouse In/Out on Tab Area of TabPage in C# Winform.

There are Event MouseLeave, MouseEnter, MouseMove, but there work for whole TabPage. I just want for Tab only.

```
TabControl tabControl = new TabControl();
TabPage tabpage = new TabPage();
tabpage.MouseMove += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(panel1_MouseMove);
tabControl.Controls.Add(tabpage);
this.Controls.Add(tabControl);
```

I'm thinking that If I get to know the Tab area so that I can write Code in MouseMove event for the same, Is there any better way to do the same.

I want for the area pointed by the arrow in the attached image.

[Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7J9Jf.png)

Comment: check the accepted answer on this posting and see if it's what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22302189/winforms-tab-page-event-not-firing

Comment: Similar: [tabcontrol SelectedTab change on mouse over](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9662083/tabcontrol-selectedtab-change-on-mouse-over)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [GetTabRect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.gettabrect(v=vs.110).aspx) function would help you here:

```
TabPage mouseTab = null;

void tabControl1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
  TabPage checkTab = null;

  for (int i = 0; i < tabControl1.TabPages.Count; ++i) {
    if (tabControl1.GetTabRect(i).Contains(e.Location)) {
      checkTab = tabControl1.TabPages[i];
      break; // To avoid unnecessary loop
    }
  }

  if (checkTab == null && mouseTab != null) {
    mouseTab = null;
  } else if (checkTab != null) {
    if (mouseTab == null || !checkTab.Equals(mouseTab)) {
      mouseTab = checkTab;
      // or do something here...
    }
  }
}
```

And to handle the mouse leaving the tab header area:

```
void tabControl1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (mouseTab != null) {
    // do something here with mouseTab...

    mouseTab = null;
  }
}
```

Comment: this is not working correctly for mouse leaving the tab.

Comment: @vivekjain Updated the example.

Comment: Is there any way to find out, which tab mouse has left in MouseLeave event?

Comment: @vivekjain Yeah, it would be the mouseTab, provided that it isn't null.

Answer (score 0):

You can place a Panel control on the whole area of the Tab, and then use the events you mentioned for that Panel control..